# Roundcube as default webmail application for whole server

Tags: hosting, webmail, roundcube

I have little cPanel web server that I offer as a convenient addition to my web development/design services to my clients.

All of them use roundcube when accessing their webmail so it would be good to skip cpanel's mail app selection page.

I know how to do it for a single account by creating subdomain webmail.domainname.com and redirecting it to roundcube, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it for all accounts on a server, instead of doing it manually.